# why THREADS in C++ gives different output on execution?

Tags: c++, multithreading

here is my code of thread programing. I am initializing the two thread like first thread `t1` is initialized using the non member function of class person and 2nd thread `t2` is initialized using a member function of person class. 
Now my doubt is why output is different at each time.

```
class person {
    int a;
public:
    person();
    person(int a):a(a){}

    void  pmemberfun() {
        cout << a;
    }    
};

void  func1() {
    cout << "\n fun1 \n";
}

int main() {
    thread t1(func1);
    //non member fun of class
    cout << "\nmain()\n";
    if (t1.joinable()) {
        t1.join();
        cout << "\njoiined1\n";
    } else {
        cout << "\nnot joinable";
    }

//using member function of class
    person a(10);
    thread t2(&person::pmemberfun, a);
    cout << "\nmain()\n";
    if (t2.joinable()) {
        t2.join();
        cout << "\njoiined\n";    
    } else {
        cout << "not joinable";
    }
```

the output when executed 1st time-

```
main()
 fun1
joiined 1
10
main()
joiined 2
```

and output when 2nd time execution is

```
 fun1
main()
joiined 1
10
main()
joiined 2
```

Comment: Read some [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) then adapt the concepts you learned there for C++ threads

Comment: Threads execute in parallel and may be scheduled in arbitrary order unless there is synchronization involved to force a specific order.

Comment: @JesperJuhl how to do in specific order??

Comment: @Rishi singh - read up on synchronization, mutex, spinlock, semaphore, condition variable, atomic operation, etc.

Comment: @JesperJuhl ok thnx :-)

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
thread t1(func1);
//non member fun of class
cout << "\nmain()\n";
```

You basically have

```
cout << "\n fun1 \n";
cout << "\nmain()\n";
```

But since `cout << "\n fun1 \n";` is inside a thread it may or may not be executed before  `cout << "\nmain()\n";` is.  You have the same thing for

```
thread t2(&person::pmemberfun, a);
cout << "\nmain()\n";
```

and even `cout << "\nnot joinable";` might print before what the thread is supposed to print since `if (t1.joinable())` could be evaluated before the thread even prints.  The only lines that will not get executed out of order are `cout << "\njoiined1\n";` since they can only happen after the thread ends.